# Get all CustomAttributes from Method and Controller inside IDocumentFilter, swashbuckle asp net core, swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

### Versions:

- Project: ASP Net Core 2.1, Web API
- Packages: Swashbuckle.AspNetCore (4.0.1)

### Problem:

I have created one `CheckIncludeForOperationFilter` class, which inherits from `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.IDocumentFilter` and implements the only method this interface requires - `public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)`.

What this class should do?
It should search for `IncludeForAttribute`. That means I should check if the action in the API has this attribute or the whole controller.

### What I have?

```cs
public class CheckIncludeForOperationFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, DocumentFilterContext context)
    {            
        foreach (var apiDescription in context.ApiDescriptions)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Here things get interesting when I start the program in debug mode, I can clearly see what the object `apiDescription` has. And it contains everything that I search. Here are the action attributes:

`apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.CustomAttributes`

and all Controller Attributes:

`apiDescription.ActionDescriptor.MethodInfo.DeclaringType.CustomAttributes`

[image]

The thing is, the compiler shows the property `MethodInfo` in debug, but it is missing when I write it. It is highlighted in red and I don't have access to it:

[image]

How can I get all the attributes?

Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this approach:

```
MethodInfo methodInfo;
var ss = apiDescription.TryGetMethodInfo(out methodInfo);
var controllerFilters = methodInfo.DeclaringType.CustomAttributes;
var actionFilters = methodInfo.DeclaringType.CustomAttributes;
```

and you will get your custom attributes.

Comment: It looks like this extension method `TryGetMethodInfo` does not exist in older versions of Swashbuckle. If you're stuck on an old version like me, try `ApiDescription.ControllerAttributes()` and `ApiDescription.ActionAttributes()`.